# Multithreading - const char array passed as parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a function as follows:

```
laodFunc(const map<uint16_t, string> & pClasses, const char * pFilePath);
```

And I'm calling it by this way. That in order to run it as a new thread with boost

```
boost::thread_group g;
stringstream myStr;
......
boost::thread *new_thread = new boost::thread(&loadFunc,classes,myStr.str().c_str());
 g.add_thread(new_thread);
```

But when I display the given path (char *) in the called method I get a wrong content:
    path ??

I would like to know please what I'm doing wrong here.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory referred to by `myStr.str().c_str()` is immedately destroyed (because the temporary `std::string` returned by `myStr.str()` is destructed), so the thread is dereferencing a dangling pointer (causing undefined behaviour).

To correct, ensure the pointer supplied to `laodFunc()` remains valid for the lifetime of thread. Or, change the `const char* pFilePath` to `std::string const& pFilePath`:

```
loadFunc(const map<uint16_t, string> & pClasses, std::string const& pFilePath);

boost::thread *new_thread = new boost::thread(&loadFunc, classes, myStr.str());
```

and a *copy* of `myStr.str()` will be stored internally and passed to the thread function (see [Thread Constructor with arguments](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor)). It is worth nothing that the `classes` argument will also be copied, even though the parameter type of `loadFunc()` is a `const&`. If desirable, this copy can be avoided by using [`boost::cref()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/ref.html):

```
boost::thread *new_thread = new boost::thread(&loadFunc,
                                              boost::cref(classes),
                                              myStr.str());
```

Comment: That is not necessarily the case, depending on the flow that is not shown, but I bet you're right!

Comment: @MartinJames, but the `std::string` is destroyed immediately. The lifetime of the `stringstream` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Since `myStr` is either a global variable used by multiple threads (so you get the value of the "latest setting of the variable", or a local variable that "disappears" after use, you will need to do something to make it persist and be unique per thread. It's not entirely clear here what your purpose is, but a "per-thread" object that holds the string, created along with the thread, and is destroyed when the thread is destroyed would work.